# Can't track why Boost-Crawler doesn't work

Tags: cron, caching, performance

I use Drupal 7.38 and [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) x - 1.0.7, and I Can't get the [Boost Crawler](https://www.drupal.org/node/1736568) to work... Boost itself is working fine (verified formation of cached webpage files at root/cache/...).

Seemingly, I did all I need to active the crawler submodule:

1. I enabled the module.
2. I went to Admin > Configure > System > Boost > Crawler, and ticked the checkbox to enable the crawler to run on cron.

After I did these stages, I ran Cron and went to `root/cache/...` and found only 3-4 cached files that where created by anonyous surfing either way... If the crawler module was working I guess I should have seen at least 60 cached-webpages there.

Since I'm not yet a programmer I have no idea how to even start dealing with this problem. The least I can do is to put here a print screen of my Recent log messages... I could paste everything seem relevant to you from there...

I very much need this submodule to work, please help!,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing may be correct behavior. **Boost Crawl** (a submodule but without its own drupal.org page) is careful to warn that; *"Minimal crawler - expires and regenerates pages **only when content is edited and on next cron run**"* [Emphasis added.] SO, it will track content that you have edited, not crawl the site and thereby refreshing the page cache.

Enabling Boost and boost crawl on my site, and then running cron (using `drush -v cron` to spy cron output) I essentially saw what you saw, in my case just my home page. Running Xenu (explained below) triggered a populating of the boost cache for my entire site. Maybe this is what you were expecting?

If you want to refresh your site's boost cache index, check out either

- [xenu link slueth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)
- [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/)
- or on Mac [SiteSucker](http://ricks-apps.com/)

You didn't ask, but each of these are invaluable web site QA tools as well.

Comment: wow! Great answer! Thank you very much, messier Screenack!

Comment: One small question, I see the Xenu link slueth & httrack are downloadable programs. Is there a way to "visit all non-cached wepages at once" from Drupal or purely online? I ask mainly to broaden general knowledge... Is it logical to assume that any broken link checker would "Activate" Boost automatically?

Comment: I haven't used it, but there is a Drupal module called [link checker](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker). So, it may be possible to run a link check from within Drupal.